# Synology 4-bay NAS: Safe to add Multiple Drives Simultaneously?

Tags: raid, nas, storage, synology

I've been using a 4-bay DS916+ with 2x4TB drives for a while and can now expand it to it's full complement of 4x4TB drives.

Is it safe to add both drives at once or is it recommended to add and expand the single disk volume one at a time?

Answer (score 3):

Looking at the Synology [website](https://www.synology.com/en-global/knowledgebase/DSM/help/DSM/StorageManager/volume_diskgroup_expand_add_disk) They appear to support multiple drives being **added** at the same time when using:

- Synology Hybrid RAID (SHR)
- JBOD
- RAID 5
- RAID 6.

You can expand the volume by adding hard disks, then tick the hard drives you want.

It appears that when you are **replacing** hard drives in a Synology NAS they must be done one at a time, according to their [knowledge base](https://www.synology.com/en-global/knowledgebase/DSM/help/DSM/StorageManager/volume_diskgroup_expand_replace_disk).